# create internal links in xslt to move to a particular location when clicked on link

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml with following data

```
<Report>
<Reference Num="1">
<Error>xyz</Error>
</Reference>
<Reference Num="2">
<Error>abc</Error>
</Reference>
<Reference Num="3">
<Error>pqr</Error>
</Reference>
</Report>
```

in the above example consider 1000 References which is actually my case

I have created a xsl to display them sequentially in the form of a table.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body >
        <table>     
            <xsl:call-template name="ReferenceList">
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ReferenceList">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Report/Reference">
        <br></br>
        <tr style="background-color: #000066; color: white;">
            <td  style="text-align:center;"> Reference </td>
            <td>ERROR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Reference<xsl:value-of select="@Num"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ERROR"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want to create links with names ref1,ref2,ref3......on the top of page so that when clicked on them it jumps to particular reference location when seen in browser.

Comment: kindly provide your tried xslt

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The input XML you show is not a well-formed document. You do not show the XSLT stylesheet you have created. Describing HTML output in prose is not very helpful, simply showing the desired HTML is much better.

Comment: @Mathias Müller sorry for insufficient information i have just started to learn xslt so i didnt know how much info to be shared to have probelm solved. Please coment if i need to give more information

Comment: Yes, you still need to give more information. Add the HTML output you need.

Comment: @Mathias Müller  i am trying to upload image of my desired output but i need 10 reputation to add a image. i am new to stack overflow

Comment: An image would not be useful anyway. You do not have to show rendered HTML, that's too vague. Please show the unrendered HTML source result you expect. If your question really is about how to create that HTML, you should ask a question about HTML.

Comment: I don't get this: you will have a table of 1000 rows - and you want to have 1000 links "on the top of page" for jumping to a particular table row? What's the point of that? 1000 links is not "the top of page" - that's more than a page all by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want to use a mode to process your nodes twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body >
        <div class="reference">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Reference" mode="links"/>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <table> 
            <thead>
              <tr style="background-color: #000066; color: white;">
                <th > Reference </th>
                <th>ERROR</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Reference"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report/Reference">
        <tr id="ref{position()}">
            <td>
                <xsl:text>Reference</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Num"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Error"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="Report/Reference" mode="links">
    <li>
      <a href="#ref{position()}">Ref<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Rendered HTML Output**

> [image]

Obviously you don't have to use a list to structure your links but I would suggest to somehow structure them and then style with CSS as needed/wanted.